# Zend merge 2 SQL statements in nested array

Tags: sql, zend-framework, loops, join

I've been trying to figure this out for a few days now. I need to have an array of values into  a master array, and it all has to come from SQL statements

```
public function fetchAllRest()
{

    $db = $this->getAdapter();
    $sql = $db->select()->from(array('c' => $this->getTableName()), array('id', 'personalId', 'name', 'number', 'email'))
    ->join(array('pd' => $this->getTableName('personal_data')), 'pd.personalId = c.personalId', array('street', 'zipcode', 'place'));

    $results = $this->getAdapter()->fetchAll($sql);
    return $results;
}
```

The code below produces an array of all records including a join with the personal data (so if i had 5 records i would get an array of 5 records).

Now i want to have the join statement (the personal_data part) to be part of the array as another array, so now we have:

```
[ 
    {1}, 
    {2}, 
    {3}, 
    {4}, 
    {5}
]
```

each value containing an array of (5+3) values (in this case JSON with key/value pairs) and this should become:

```
[ 
    {1 
        {"personal_data" : "name", "number", "email"}
    }, 
    {2 
        {"personal_data" : "name", "number", "email"}
    }, 
    {3 
        {"personal_data" : "name", "number", "email"}
    }, 
    {4 
        {"personal_data" : "name", "number", "email"}
    }, 
    {5 
        {"personal_data" : "name", "number", "email"}
    }
]
```

So a custom named value in the original array with the value 'personal_data' containing all personal_data for that record.

I tried looping through each SQL but it produced too many statements resulting in some mysql-bytes-error

Any solutions?

Thanks in advance

EDIT: I tried the following:

```
foreach($results as $r) {
        $results[$i]["personal_data"] = array('personalDataId' => $results[$i]['personalDataId'],
                'name' => $results[$i]['name'],
                'number' => $results[$i]['number'],
                'email' => $results[$i]['email'];
        $i++;
    }
    return $results;
```

Too bad this didnt work out the way i'd like to, cause in order to access the values in the array they already have to be there (resulting in a subarray with data that is already in the hash). I'm now looking into removing these excess data but it sounds very inconvenient to remove data i initially added

Comment: Why don't you loop through `$results` and create another array, then `json_encode` it?

Comment: is that the fastest way to do it? i happen to have a few thousand records and when i loop through all of them the statement exceeds 30 seconds which quits the request automatically.

By looping you mean running another sql statement on for instance $results[0] to $results[2124] right? Or is there an easier way to already turn the fetched data into a subarray?

Comment: Yes I'd fetch all necessary data with one SQL query, then process it using PHP. I do not know a way to generate associative arrays like this using a query. I think once concern would be memory limit if you are dealing with thousands of records.

Comment: I edited my comment with the thing i tried, too bad its not a good solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this after you get `$results`:

```
$jsonArray = array();
foreach ( $results as $result ) {
    $jsonArray[] = array( 'personal_data' => array(
        'id' => $result->id,
        'name' => $result->name,
        'street' => $result->street,
        ...
    ));
}

return $jsonArray;
```

Comment: hmm this is kinda what i edited just now to the original question. im trying to do this right now, please note that the $results contain a regular array, i only json_encode it in the view

Comment: thanks for the answer, i decided to pick all data i needed from the sql generated, seemed to be the best way.